# Concatenate range of ranges to range

Tags: c++, range-v3

Let `rw = ranges::views`.

I'm trying to create exclusively using `range-v3` an analog of the construction:

```
std::vector<int> v;

// range = {0, 1, 2}
auto range = rw::ints (0, 3);

for (int i : range)
    for (int j : range)
        v.push_back (func (i, j))

// v = {func (0, 0), func (0, 1), func (0, 2),
//      func (1, 0), func (1, 1), func (1, 2),
//      func (2, 0), func (2, 1), func (2, 2)}
```

I tried the following option:

```
// range = {0, 1, 2}
auto range = rw::ints (0, 3);

// range_of_ranges = {{func (0, 0), func (0, 1), func (0, 2)},
//                    {func (1, 0), func (1, 1), func (1, 2)},
//                    {func (2, 0), func (2, 1), func (2, 2)}}
auto range_of_ranges = rw::transform (range, [] (int i) {
    return rw::transform (range, [i] (int j) { return func (i, j); });
});

// result = {func (0, 0), func (0, 1), func (0, 2),
//           func (1, 0), func (1, 1), func (1, 2),
//           func (2, 0), func (2, 1), func (2, 2)}
auto result = rw::concat (range, range, range);

for (auto x : result)
    printf ("%d\n", x);
```

But if I replace

```
// result = {func (0, 0), func (0, 1), func (0, 2),
//           func (1, 0), func (1, 1), func (1, 2),
//           func (2, 0), func (2, 1), func (2, 2)}
auto result = rw::concat (range, range, range);
```

with

```
// result = { {{func (0, 0), func (0, 1), func (0, 2)},
//             {func (1, 0), func (1, 1), func (1, 2)},
//             {func (2, 0), func (2, 1), func (2, 2)}} }
auto result = rw::concat (range_of_ranges);
```

there will be a compiler warning:

```
warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'ranges::iota_view<int, int>' [-Wformat]
    printf ("%d\n", x);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I don't really understand how to fix it properly. I understand that the concat function should take its arguments and combine them into a range and I just created a range of length 1, but I do not know which solution would be correct. Could you give me a hint?

**UPD[1] (based on [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) comment: `range-v3` has `views::cartesian_product`)**:
It turned out to simplify the code to the following:

```
auto range = rw::ints (0, 3);

auto cart_prod = rw::cartesian_product (range, range);

auto unpack_args_and_call_func = [] (const auto &arg) {
    return std::apply (func, arg);
};

auto result = rw::transform (cart_prod, unpack_args_and_call_func);
```

However, using the unpacking argument does not look very nice and convenient.

**UPD[2] (based on [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) comment: There are also `views::join` for your `range_of_ranges`)**:
Replace

```
// result = {func (0, 0), func (0, 1), func (0, 2),
//           func (1, 0), func (1, 1), func (1, 2),
//           func (2, 0), func (2, 1), func (2, 2)}
auto result = rw::concat (range, range, range);
```

with

```
// result = { {{func (0, 0), func (0, 1), func (0, 2)},
//             {func (1, 0), func (1, 1), func (1, 2)},
//             {func (2, 0), func (2, 1), func (2, 2)}} }
auto result = rw::join (range_of_ranges);
```

Comment: range-v3 has `views::cartesian_product`

Comment: There are also `views::join` for your `range_of_ranges`.

Comment: *"using the unpacking argument does not look very nice and convenient."* opinion based... I find it clearer than your imbricated `transform`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42).

```
// range = {0, 1, 2}
auto range = rw::ints (0, 3);

// range_of_ranges = {{func (0, 0), func (0, 1), func (0, 2)},
//                    {func (1, 0), func (1, 1), func (1, 2)},
//                    {func (2, 0), func (2, 1), func (2, 2)}}
auto range_of_ranges = rw::transform (range, [] (int i) {
    return rw::transform (range, [i] (int j) { return func (i, j); });
});

// result = {func (0, 0), func (0, 1), func (0, 2),
//           func (1, 0), func (1, 1), func (1, 2),
//           func (2, 0), func (2, 1), func (2, 2)}
auto result = rw::join (range_of_ranges);

for (auto x : result)
    printf ("%d\n", x);
```